# Centering a tabularx

Tags: horizontal-alignment, tabularx

I want to center a `tabularx`, not the cells content, but the table itself. 
Reading things about `tabular`, I tried `\centering`.

Here is my mwe:

```
% arara: xelatex
% arara: xelatex

\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcolumntype{°}{>{\global\let\currentrowstyle\relax}}
\newcolumntype{^}{>{\currentrowstyle}}

\begin{document}

{\small
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{200pt}{@{}°c^c^c@{}}
a & b & c
\\
d & e & f
\\
\end{tabularx}
}

\end{document}
```

It normally renders the `tabularx`, but not centered.
I also tried `\begin{center}\end{center}` but without any success.

How do I center it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Since it is \linewidth wide, just using `\noindent` should be enough.

Comment: Thanks.

Where do I put the `\noindent`?

Comment: Just before  `\begin{tabularx}`.

Comment: It didn't work.

Comment: Why were you in such a hurry to "accept" one of the answers? On this site, it's usually a good idea to wait a while, but at least several hours, before "accepting" the best of (hopefully) several answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use tabularx that needs at least one column of type X wich adjusts its width to fill and fit the width you gave initially as parameter.

Secondly you ask for a tabular of all linewidth. That means already centered as using all free space.

Here is something centered with one X column.

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcolumntype{°}{>{\global\let\currentrowstyle\relax}}
\newcolumntype{^}{>{\currentrowstyle}}

\begin{document}

Left\dotfill

\begin{center}
\small
\begin{tabularx}{.5\linewidth}{@{}°c^Xc@{}}\hline
a & b & c
\\
d & e & f
\\\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{center}

\dotfill Right

{\small
\hfill\begin{tabularx}{.5\linewidth}{@{}°c^Xc@{}}\hline
a & b & c
\\
d & e & f
\\\hline
\end{tabularx}\hfill\strut
}

Left\dotfill
\end{document}
```

Comment: I've edited my example for a more generic case, but the solution you provided works for any width, thanks!

Do you know why `\centering` doesn't work even with a `X` column?

Comment: @MarcSharma - `\centering` works just fine with `X`-type columns; see my answer for an example.

Comment: @Mico I think he OP wants to center the tabular not the comlum.

Comment: @MarcSharma In don't know why centering nor Centering don't work. To center something without the loss of vertical space of \begin{center} I use hfill. See my edit. You can upvote the different answers if they a glad to you.

Comment: @Tarass - Since the OP's `tabularx` environment has width `\textwidth`, I don't think there's much to do in terms of centering the `tabularx` within the confines of the text block.

Comment: @Mico I guessed well is question as his edit says clearely "I want to center a tabularx, not the cells content, but the table itself. " He missuses tabularx two times - no X column - full linewidth. I upvoted your answer ;-)

Comment: @Tarass - Thanks! I've upvoted your answer too in the meantime. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that (a) uses three centered "X"-type columns and (b) uses `\noindent` before `\begin{tabularx}...` to assure that the `tabularx` environment occupies the full width of the textblock. I've also removed the `°` and `^` column specifications as they don't seem to do anything. (However, I may be wrong...)

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
%\usepackage{array} %% 'array' is loaded automatically by 'tabularx'
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} % centered version of 'X' col. type

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} CCC @{}}
\toprule
a & b & c \\
d & e & f \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Altough in my actual document I use a similar column than the one you defined, my question was about centering the table, not the columns content.

Still, thanks for your example.

Comment: @MarcSharma - In the original version of your query, you specified the desired width of the tabular material to be `\textwidth`. That's the query my answer was designed to anwer. I've notice that you've changed the width specification drastically in the meantime.

Comment: @Mico Maybe consecutively to my answer.